# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.scalacheck.Arbitrary

Tags: scala, context-bound

I was trying to use a method called `random` with the following signature:

```
def random[T: WeakTypeTag: Arbitrary]: T
```

On a case class named `Checking` but I get this :

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
>   org.scalacheck.Arbitrary[com.organization.lambda.Checking]

I know this is due to some issues with context bounds, but I can't get my head around that and understand what has to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use [random-data-generator-magnolia](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator-magnolia)?

If so, you should specify implicit value for Arbitrary[Checking] case class.

Example from [test source](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator-magnolia/blob/9616f1c0c765eb1f12823234fe3df7feb66ebb98/src/test/scala/com/danielasfregola/randomdatagenerator/magnolia/RandomDataGeneratorSpec.scala#L52):

```
implicit val arbitraryPerson: Arbitrary[Person] = Arbitrary {
  for {
    name <- Gen.oneOf("Daniela", "John", "Martin", "Marco")
    age <- Gen.choose(0, 100)
  } yield Person(name, age)
}

val instance = random[Person]
```

Person is:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Comment: Hello @Duelist. I bump into the same issue using `random-data-generator`, version 2.9, scala 2.13. Should I specify a custom `Arbitrary[MyClass]` even if I don't use `magnolia` package? Error is
 `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.scalacheck.Arbitrary[my.org.MyClass]` and my case class owns types like `java.sql.Timestamp` and `enumeratum` enums. The rest of them are primitives. Thank you.

Comment: @spi-x-i you have to provide `Artbitrary[java.sql.Timestamp]`. Scala types, case classes, enumerations are automatically derived via Shapeless, but afraid it doesn't work for java types.